# how to copy and paste values and formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, paste

I have the following code that will copy my data to a blank row.  However, I cant figure out how to copy the values and formatting.

```
Sub PasteValues()

  Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:P12").Copy
  Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste in values and formatting seperately, as per the below:

```
Sub PasteValues()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlValues
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlFormats

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

You'll obviously need to adapt to your own code, but it shows the principle.